# How can I use the value of the ComboBox to multiply with the NumericUpDown in C#?

Tags: c#, combobox, numericupdown

[image]

I need help on how can I compute for the Basic Pay which is the Rate/Day * No. of days worked.

How can I get the values of every position code so that I can multiply it to the No. of Days Worked.

For example when I enter position code A, the rate/day is 500. That should do 500 * 2 so that my basic pay would come out as 1000.

I need help please. Thanks in advance!!

Comment: if you get an answer that helps you to solve your problem, you should mark it as accepted. [Here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) is explained how it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your `NumericUpDown` control, there's an event called `ValueChanged`, you can use that to compute the *basic pay* of the employee based on your ComboBox value.

You can use this code to automatically compute the `basic bay` of your employee base on the *number of days worked*

```
private void NumericUpDown1_ValueChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(cmbPositionCode.SelectedItem == "Code A")
        txtBasicPay.Text = 500 * NumericUpDown1.Value;
    else if(cmbPositionCode.SelectedItem == "Code B")
        txtBasicPay.Text = 600 * NumericUpDown1.Value;
    ...
}
```

**Edit:**

So you want to use the `compute` button to compute the basic pay which is almost the same as above but you will put the code in the `Click` event of your `Compute` button

```
private void btnCompute_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(cmbPositionCode.SelectedItem == "Code A")
            txtBasicPay.Text = 500 * NumericUpDown1.Value;
        else if(cmbPositionCode.SelectedItem == "Code B")
            txtBasicPay.Text = 600 * NumericUpDown1.Value;
        ...
    }
```

Comment: I did it like this

decimal txtBasic;
   
 if(cmbPositionCode.SelectedItem == "A")
        txtBasic = 500 * numericUpDown1.Value;
  
    else if(cmbPositionCode.SelectedItem == "B")
        txtBasic = 400 * numericUpDown1.Value;
    
    else if (cmbPositionCode.SelectedItem == "C");
     txtBasic = 300 * numericUpDown1.Value;  


How can I use my compute button into computing it and putting the answer in my textbox for Basic Pay txtBasic

Comment: @MikaelaNera I'll edit my post and provide the answer

Comment: I have already put it in my button but the Basic Pay does not show up on my text box

Comment: @MikaelaNera oh I forgot to put the `Text` of the textbox on the code, I already fix it though.

Comment: Hello i have already put the .Text earlier and now it says cannot implicitly convert type 'decimal' to 'string'

Comment: Well you need to convert it to `string`

Comment: Yes. I was asking about how to convert it but nevermind It is now running.

Comment: Great! You can upvote my answer at approved it if it helps you.